# Different behavior when using Debug/Run button and F5/Ctrl+F5 in Visual Studio Code (Python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to pass an argument to a python script and I'm using a standard "Python file" debug configuration with the "launch.json" file for this purpose. I have defined the argument in my debug configuration  ( "args": ["car"] )and started to run the script with F5.
It is working. The application has access to the passed argument.

However, if i try to CLICK on the "Run Python File" button in the upper right corner of my editor the script crashes because of no argument was passed to it.

Same goes for "Debug Python File"-Button and Ctrl+F5. Ctrl+F5 works, clicking the button does not.

What is the issue here?

The code I am trying to run with a passed argument:

https://github.com/RGGH/ebay_api_postgres/blob/main/ebay_21.py

Answer (score 2):

"Run Python FIle" and "Debug Python File" don't run the "project", so they don't grab the argument from the project configuration.  Use F5 and Ctrl-F5, or run in the terminal.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. The VSCode documentation doesn't mention that there is a difference.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging

Thank you for your help

Comment: That is a valid complaint.  Those of us who have used Visual Studio for decades (long before VSCode) know that "Compile this file" and "Compile the project" are two different concepts, but it's probably not clear right out of the box.

Comment: @ToBeDefined Yes, it is. Like Tim Roberts's explanation, you can get the commands in the terminal, you will find "Run Python FIle" and "Debug Python File" will not invoke the arguments you defined in the launch.json except you take F5 or Ctrl+F5. It just means run the python file. And of course, you can run the python file in the terminal directly and adds the arguments manually.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is. Like Tim Roberts's explanation, you can get the executed commands in the terminal, you will find `Run Python FIle` and `Debug Python File` will not invoke the arguments you defined in the launch.json except you take `F5` or `Ctrl+F5`. They just run the python file.

And of course, you can run the python file in the terminal directly and adds the arguments manually.